# How to evolve trade Pokemon on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: mojave

I am playing Pokemon Fire Red on VBA emulator mac.

I can’t seem to find an emulator that I can plug and play and evolve traded Pokemon for MacBook.

I have tried to install 2 versions of VBA on my Mac, however, they fail when trying to trade Pokemon and have connection failures.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: While this is on-topic as such, you might get better answers on whatever forum there is for the emulator you are using.

Comment: Thanks, my rating wasn’t high enough to make a new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution on how to trade pokemon.

Prerequisites:

BACK UP YOUR SAVE FILES FIRST!

I have lost a few saves and sometimes the namespacing can change on a filename, so I would advise you save your files and find out where your saves are stored too so if you need to re name them afterwards, you can do.

See this on how to get your IP address https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/h...

Here are the key steps in the video:

A - Before trading

1 - Download VBA - M from GitHub

https://github.com/visualboyadvance-m...

Install the right version for your system, I have installed the 64 bit.

2 - Copy VBA - M to Applications folder

3 - Copy VBA - M in the Applications folder so that you have 2 VBAs, in there as shown in the video.

4 - Make sure that the games actively run in the background first before any trading, so that you can have both Fire Red and Leaf Green active at not frozen if not selected.

5 - Always use a keyboard to control the VBA and not a Bluetooth controller - if you use a Bluetooth controller, it also controls the game in the background which is not what you want, so have the keyboard set up first.

B - Starting the trade

6 - Open both VBAs up, do not load the game, just open them

7 - Go to link, select link type as cable (not wireless)

8 - Start network link, set one as server with your IP address, and the other VBA as client.

9 - They should connect

10 - load the games

11 - Complete the trade

12 - Save the game afterward

13 - Check your saves and it should all be there

I have also shown how to achieve this in a YouTube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdbJsnWkZVc